# Используя массив строк создать Map где ключ длина строки, а значение сколько строк с этой длиной

Tags: java

я знаю как получить длину строки, но никак не понимаю как найти в массиве количество строк с этой длиной:

```
public void map(String... array) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    Collection <String> collection = Arrays.asList(array);
    for (String string : array) {
        int key = string.length();
                                   // value
        hashMap.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void map(String... array) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    Collection<String> collection = Arrays.asList(array);
    for (String string : array) {
        int key = string.length();
        if(hashMap.containsKey(key)) {
            hashMap.put(key, hashMap.get(key) + 1);
        } else {
            hashMap.put(key, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Кхм, кхм. Чем это отличается от моего ответа?